# Multi-level list InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, numbering, cross-reference, lists

I am formating a book chapter and got stuck with tables, figures and sections numberings. I am trying for days. Can someone help me please?

The book is organised like this:

**Chapter 1 Title** (This is not a numbered list. It is a text frame with its own paragraph style and I change it manually)

Some introductory paragraph. (The style of this first paragraph is different because it has a Drop Cap character and every chapter starts with it, but it is based on the normal "Body" paragraph style).

*Figure 1.* Caption

*Table 1.* Caption

**Primary Section 1**

*Figure 2.* Caption

**Secondary section 1**

*Figure 3.* Caption

*Table 2.* Caption

**Tertiary section 1**

**Secondary section 2**

*Figure 4.* Caption

*Table 3.* Caption

**Primary section 2**

*Figure 5.* Caption

*Table 4.* Caption

End of chapter.

Chapter 2... and so on (See figure 1)

[image: **Figure 1.** This is how the book is divided. The text frames *between* chapters are *unthreaded*. Text frames *within* chapters, **are** threaded.]

---

I need all lists to restart in every chapter. As we can see in the image, they

I have one paragraph style for each list.

It is also important to mention that **figures 1, 2...** and **Chapter 1, 2...** are not in the same frames as the other elements. But they're all in the same layer. I don't know if this affects the lists' behavior.

I played with the list levels, created other lists and I just couldn't do it.

I tried to set my Drop Cap paragraph as a Level 1 numered list with no numbering, so it could restart the other lists, theoretically. It didn't worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***If working with a .INDB file (Indesign book), with separate docs as chapters:***

*Primary section*: set as numbered list - level **1**. Create a new list, **uncheck** "Continue Numbers From Previous Document In Book" in the options, then name and save the list. (No need to set your "Drop cap" paragraph as a list)

*Secondary section*: set as numbered list - level **2**. Select previously created List. **Check** "Restart Numbers At This Level After any previous level.

*Tertiary section*: set as numbered list - level **3**. Select previously created List.  **Check** "Restart Numbers At This Level After any previous level.

*Figure*: set as numbered list - level **4**. Select previously created List. **Uncheck** "Restart Numbers At This Level After any previous level.

*Table*: set as numbered list - level **5**. Select previously created List. **Uncheck** "Restart Numbers At This Level After any previous level.

For all, select Mode: "Continue From Previous Number"

Don't forget to synchronize docs and - most important thing - to **update all numbers** in the book panel options.
Of course, you can set Figure (and Tables) Numbered list option as "Figure ^#.^t", so you won't have to type "figure" (or "table") every time.

***If working in a single .INDD file, with threaded frames***

Same process than above with one difference:
*Primary section*: In your list options **uncheck** "Continue Numbers Across Stories".
**Important**: please note that it means that text frames must be threaded, otherwise, sections numbering will restart at 1
[image: Thread]

***If working in a single .INDD file, with unthreaded frames***

*Chapter*: set as numbered list - level 1. Create a new list, **check** "Continue Numbers Across Stories" in the options. Leave "Numbers" section blank and set Mode to "Start at..."

[image: Chapter]

Adjust other sections levels: *Primary section* > level 2, *Secondary section* > level 3, and so on...

In figure and table para styles, set "Restart Numbers At" option to **1**:

[image: figure]

[image: Unthreaded]

Comment: Hi Vinny! I followed the steps exactly as you sad. But it didn't work. The primary section didn't restarted as the chapters changed. But I am not using the book (.indb), I am using an InDesign document (.indd). Do you think is that the problem?

Comment: HI Guilherme. Oh right... I understood you were working with.indb. So I edited my answer to fit to your request. Hope that helps, tell me if doesn't... Screenshot may also help to understand request.

Comment: Hi @Vinny! I edited my question to add the screenshot. I followed step by step your recommendations. It worked! Thank you very much! I also tried to vary between paragraph styles and the threaded and unthreaded frames. The funny thing is that now I can't reproduce my mistakes. Seems like no matter what I do (thread or unthread... etc) I get the desired output. So I am not 100% sure of what's going on... What does the number "1" you selected in "Restart numbers at" stand for? (See your image the shows "figure" para style) I didn't know we were able to put numbers in that field. Thanks again!